# Issue jHipster npm start

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, jhipster

I'm running a jhipster project in my MacBook Pro laptop (macOS Mojave v.10.14.4), when it finished of compiling successfully with npm start.

It continues compiling many times without doing any change or modification to the code, it deploys the next error after a while:

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 10362ms                              

No type errors found
Version: typescript 3.4.5
Time: 54ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣:    776 modules
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
/Volumes/KINGSTON 1/be4techbackend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/servers/SockJSServer.js:67
      f(connection, connection.headers);
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of null
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Volumes/KINGSTON 1/be4techbackend/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/servers/SockJSServer.js:67:32)
    at Server.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at App.emit (/Volumes/KINGSTON 1/be4techbackend/node_modules/sockjs/lib/sockjs.js:196:29)
    at /Volumes/KINGSTON 1/be4techbackend/node_modules/sockjs/lib/transport.js:111:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! be-4-tech-app-1@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack-dev-server: `node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js "--config" "webpack/webpack.dev.js" "--inline" "--hot" "--port=9060" "--watch-content-base" "--env.stats=minimal"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the be-4-tech-app-1@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack-dev-server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/victorhiguita/.npm/_logs/2020-03-04T00_58_49_205Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! be-4-tech-app-1@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:dev: `npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --inline --hot --port=9060 --watch-content-base --env.stats=minimal`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the be-4-tech-app-1@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webpack:dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/victorhiguita/.npm/_logs/2020-03-04T00_58_49_239Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! be-4-tech-app-1@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start: `npm run webpack:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the be-4-tech-app-1@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/victorhiguita/.npm/_logs/2020-03-04T00_58_49_264Z-debug.log
```

Thanks for any clue.

Comment: Is your `KINGSTON 1` big enough for `node_modules`? Have you tried to copy and run the app on a builtin volume?

Comment: It is a removable disc, I copied it to the local machine, I executed it and it's working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix released: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2199.

It seems that the update of npm, as well as rebuilding of node_modules after copying from external media to the internal drive fixed the error.